# Securing root directory in IIS with Shibboleth SAML/SSO by not setting specific path

Tags: shibboleth

The sample shibboleth2.xml document shows this for IIS under the RequestMap node:

```
<Host name="domain.com">
    <Path name="secure" authType="shibboleth" requireSession="true"/>
</Host>
```

That indeed locks down the "secure" directory at domain.com/secure. However, what if I just want to secure domain.com but not any specific subdirectory?

How do I secure the root directory and still apply the authType and requireSession, in other words?

I tried putting nothing "" in that space and also just a slash (/), but that doesn't seem to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to move the `authType="shibboleth"` and `requireSession="true"` elements to the `<Host>` RequestMap configuration, i.e. replace yours with:

```
<Host name="domain.com" authType="shibboleth" requireSession="true" />
```

See: https://wiki.shibboleth.net/confluence/display/SP3/Host

Comment: Your answer makes sense, but I sure wasn't able to figure that out by reading the wiki, which I had already done. I'll give it a try soon. Thanks!